# clickhouse 1 node out of 3 not syncing

Tags: clickhouse

I have a 3-node clickhouse cluster, almost identical to the setup in https://github.com/tetafro/clickhouse-cluster.

I ran the CREATE TABLE statement on the 3 nodes, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE replica_test.hits_shard
(
 `WatchID` UInt64,
 `JavaEnable` UInt8,
 `Title` String,
 `GoodEvent` Int16,
 `EventTime` DateTime,
 `EventDate` Date,
 `CounterID` UInt32,
 `ClientIP` UInt32,
 `ClientIP6` FixedString(16),
 `RegionID` UInt32,
 `UserID` UInt64,
 `CounterClass` Int8,
 `OS` UInt8,
 `UserAgent` UInt8,
 `URL` String,
 `Referer` String,
 `URLDomain` String,
 `RefererDomain` String,
 `Refresh` UInt8,
 `IsRobot` UInt8,
 `RefererCategories` Array(UInt16),
 `URLCategories` Array(UInt16),
 `URLRegions` Array(UInt32),
 `RefererRegions` Array(UInt32),
 `ResolutionWidth` UInt16,
 `ResolutionHeight` UInt16,
 `ResolutionDepth` UInt8,
 `FlashMajor` UInt8,
 `FlashMinor` UInt8,
 `FlashMinor2` String,
 `NetMajor` UInt8,
 `NetMinor` UInt8,
 `UserAgentMajor` UInt16,
 `UserAgentMinor` FixedString(2),
 `CookieEnable` UInt8,
 `JavascriptEnable` UInt8,
 `IsMobile` UInt8,
 `MobilePhone` UInt8,
 `MobilePhoneModel` String,
 `Params` String,
 `IPNetworkID` UInt32,
 `TraficSourceID` Int8,
 `SearchEngineID` UInt16,
 `SearchPhrase` String,
 `AdvEngineID` UInt8,
 `IsArtifical` UInt8,
 `WindowClientWidth` UInt16,
 `WindowClientHeight` UInt16,
 `ClientTimeZone` Int16,
 `ClientEventTime` DateTime,
 `SilverlightVersion1` UInt8,
 `SilverlightVersion2` UInt8,
 `SilverlightVersion3` UInt32,
 `SilverlightVersion4` UInt16,
 `PageCharset` String,
 `CodeVersion` UInt32,
 `IsLink` UInt8,
 `IsDownload` UInt8,
 `IsNotBounce` UInt8,
 `FUniqID` UInt64,
 `HID` UInt32,
 `IsOldCounter` UInt8,
 `IsEvent` UInt8,
 `IsParameter` UInt8,
 `DontCountHits` UInt8,
 `WithHash` UInt8,
 `HitColor` FixedString(1),
 `UTCEventTime` DateTime,
 `Age` UInt8,
 `Sex` UInt8,
 `Income` UInt8,
 `Interests` UInt16,
 `Robotness` UInt8,
 `GeneralInterests` Array(UInt16),
 `RemoteIP` UInt32,
 `RemoteIP6` FixedString(16),
 `WindowName` Int32,
 `OpenerName` Int32,
 `HistoryLength` Int16,
 `BrowserLanguage` FixedString(2),
 `BrowserCountry` FixedString(2),
 `SocialNetwork` String,
 `SocialAction` String,
 `HTTPError` UInt16,
 `SendTiming` Int32,
 `DNSTiming` Int32,
 `ConnectTiming` Int32,
 `ResponseStartTiming` Int32,
 `ResponseEndTiming` Int32,
 `FetchTiming` Int32,
 `RedirectTiming` Int32,
 `DOMInteractiveTiming` Int32,
 `DOMContentLoadedTiming` Int32,
 `DOMCompleteTiming` Int32,
 `LoadEventStartTiming` Int32,
 `LoadEventEndTiming` Int32,
 `NSToDOMContentLoadedTiming` Int32,
 `FirstPaintTiming` Int32,
 `RedirectCount` Int8,
 `SocialSourceNetworkID` UInt8,
 `SocialSourcePage` String,
 `ParamPrice` Int64,
 `ParamOrderID` String,
 `ParamCurrency` FixedString(3),
 `ParamCurrencyID` UInt16,
 `GoalsReached` Array(UInt32),
 `OpenstatServiceName` String,
 `OpenstatCampaignID` String,
 `OpenstatAdID` String,
 `OpenstatSourceID` String,
 `UTMSource` String,
 `UTMMedium` String,
 `UTMCampaign` String,
 `UTMContent` String,
 `UTMTerm` String,
 `FromTag` String,
 `HasGCLID` UInt8,
 `RefererHash` UInt64,
 `URLHash` UInt64,
 `CLID` UInt32,
 `YCLID` UInt64,
 `ShareService` String,
 `ShareURL` String,
 `ShareTitle` String,
 `ParsedParams` Nested(
 Key1 String,
 Key2 String,
 Key3 String,
 Key4 String,
 Key5 String,
 ValueDouble Float64),
 `IslandID` FixedString(16),
 `RequestNum` UInt32,
 `RequestTry` UInt8
)
ENGINE=ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/tables/hits', '{replica}')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(EventDate)
ORDER BY (CounterID, EventDate, intHash32(UserID))
SAMPLE BY intHash32(UserID);


CREATE TABLE replica_test.hits_distributed
(
 `WatchID` UInt64,
 `JavaEnable` UInt8,
 `Title` String,
 `GoodEvent` Int16,
 `EventTime` DateTime,
 `EventDate` Date,
 `CounterID` UInt32,
 `ClientIP` UInt32,
 `ClientIP6` FixedString(16),
 `RegionID` UInt32,
 `UserID` UInt64,
 `CounterClass` Int8,
 `OS` UInt8,
 `UserAgent` UInt8,
 `URL` String,
 `Referer` String,
 `URLDomain` String,
 `RefererDomain` String,
 `Refresh` UInt8,
 `IsRobot` UInt8,
 `RefererCategories` Array(UInt16),
 `URLCategories` Array(UInt16),
 `URLRegions` Array(UInt32),
 `RefererRegions` Array(UInt32),
 `ResolutionWidth` UInt16,
 `ResolutionHeight` UInt16,
 `ResolutionDepth` UInt8,
 `FlashMajor` UInt8,
 `FlashMinor` UInt8,
 `FlashMinor2` String,
 `NetMajor` UInt8,
 `NetMinor` UInt8,
 `UserAgentMajor` UInt16,
 `UserAgentMinor` FixedString(2),
 `CookieEnable` UInt8,
 `JavascriptEnable` UInt8,
 `IsMobile` UInt8,
 `MobilePhone` UInt8,
 `MobilePhoneModel` String,
 `Params` String,
 `IPNetworkID` UInt32,
 `TraficSourceID` Int8,
 `SearchEngineID` UInt16,
 `SearchPhrase` String,
 `AdvEngineID` UInt8,
 `IsArtifical` UInt8,
 `WindowClientWidth` UInt16,
 `WindowClientHeight` UInt16,
 `ClientTimeZone` Int16,
 `ClientEventTime` DateTime,
 `SilverlightVersion1` UInt8,
 `SilverlightVersion2` UInt8,
 `SilverlightVersion3` UInt32,
 `SilverlightVersion4` UInt16,
 `PageCharset` String,
 `CodeVersion` UInt32,
 `IsLink` UInt8,
 `IsDownload` UInt8,
 `IsNotBounce` UInt8,
 `FUniqID` UInt64,
 `HID` UInt32,
 `IsOldCounter` UInt8,
 `IsEvent` UInt8,
 `IsParameter` UInt8,
 `DontCountHits` UInt8,
 `WithHash` UInt8,
 `HitColor` FixedString(1),
 `UTCEventTime` DateTime,
 `Age` UInt8,
 `Sex` UInt8,
 `Income` UInt8,
 `Interests` UInt16,
 `Robotness` UInt8,
 `GeneralInterests` Array(UInt16),
 `RemoteIP` UInt32,
 `RemoteIP6` FixedString(16),
 `WindowName` Int32,
 `OpenerName` Int32,
 `HistoryLength` Int16,
 `BrowserLanguage` FixedString(2),
 `BrowserCountry` FixedString(2),
 `SocialNetwork` String,
 `SocialAction` String,
 `HTTPError` UInt16,
 `SendTiming` Int32,
 `DNSTiming` Int32,
 `ConnectTiming` Int32,
 `ResponseStartTiming` Int32,
 `ResponseEndTiming` Int32,
 `FetchTiming` Int32,
 `RedirectTiming` Int32,
 `DOMInteractiveTiming` Int32,
 `DOMContentLoadedTiming` Int32,
 `DOMCompleteTiming` Int32,
 `LoadEventStartTiming` Int32,
 `LoadEventEndTiming` Int32,
 `NSToDOMContentLoadedTiming` Int32,
  `FirstPaintTiming` Int32,
 `RedirectCount` Int8,
 `SocialSourceNetworkID` UInt8,
 `SocialSourcePage` String,
 `ParamPrice` Int64,
 `ParamOrderID` String,
 `ParamCurrency` FixedString(3),
 `ParamCurrencyID` UInt16,
 `GoalsReached` Array(UInt32),
 `OpenstatServiceName` String,
 `OpenstatCampaignID` String,
 `OpenstatAdID` String,
 `OpenstatSourceID` String,
 `UTMSource` String,
 `UTMMedium` String,
 `UTMCampaign` String,
 `UTMContent` String,
 `UTMTerm` String,
 `FromTag` String,
 `HasGCLID` UInt8,
 `RefererHash` UInt64,
 `URLHash` UInt64,
 `CLID` UInt32,
 `YCLID` UInt64,
 `ShareService` String,
 `ShareURL` String,
 `ShareTitle` String,
 `ParsedParams.Key1` Array(String),
 `ParsedParams.Key2` Array(String),
 `ParsedParams.Key3` Array(String),
 `ParsedParams.Key4` Array(String),
 `ParsedParams.Key5` Array(String),
 `ParsedParams.ValueDouble` Array(Float64),
 `IslandID` FixedString(16),
 `RequestNum` UInt32,
 `RequestTry` UInt8
)
ENGINE = Distributed('hivestack', replica_test, 'hits_shard', rand());
```

I have an out-of-sync issue with node-2 as follows:

- if i insert data to node-2, the data is only seen by node-2

  - insert ... into node2 => hits_shard then select count(*) fom node1 => hits_shard the result is 0
- if i insert data into node-1 or node-3, it's seen by all 3 nodes.

```
SELECT * from system.replicas:
replica_test,hits_shard,ReplicatedMergeTree,1,1,0,0,0,0,/clickhouse/tables/02/tables/hits,clickhouse02,/clickhouse/tables/02/tables/hits/replicas/clickhouse02,-1,0,0,0,0,1969-12-31 19:00:00,1969-12-31 19:00:00,1969-12-31 19:00:00,1969-12-31 19:00:00,"","","",0,0,1969-12-31 19:00:00,0,1,1,"","",{'clickhouse02':1}
```

`select * from system.replication_queue` is empty

clickhouse version: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:22.4.5.9
zookeeper version: bitnami/zookeeper:3.8.0

I verified that all 3 nodes can talk to each others via clickhouse-client and nc  9000

Would appreciate any tips on how to debug/fix this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the same zookeeper clickhouse settings on all 3 nodes?

Do you insert into `Distributed` table or insert into `ReplicatedMergeTree`?

For first case, check on node-2

```
SELECT * FROM system.distribution_queue FORMAT Vertical
SELECT * FROM system.clusters FORMAT Vertical
```

and compare `<remote_servers>` section in your config for all 3 nodes

Comment: I had to delete the cluster and recreate it, that works now. To answer your question though, the `system.distribution_queue` table empty on node2 and i made sure i was inserting to the _distributed table.